# How to form dataframes from a particular dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe (say) of 25 columns as follows:

```
A         B         C       ......   I             J    ......... Y

I-1       yes       3               1-2-2017       100           james

I-2       no        4               NaN            100           ashok

I-3       NaN       9               2-10-2017      5             mary

I-4       yes       NaN             2-10-2017      0             sania
```

I would like to obtain 3 dataframes from the above dataframe such that

a) the first dataframe consists of columns A to G

b) the second dataframe consists of column A and columns I to J.

c) the third dataframe consists of column A and columns K to Y.

How should I approach it ? (Preferably in Python. Only some column values are illustrated. I will show more if required.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new DataFrames by using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in combination with [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join):

```
df_a_to_g = df.loc[:, 'A':'G']
df_a_and_i_to_j = df.loc[:, ['A']].join(df.loc[:, 'I':'J'])
df_a_and_k_to_y = df.loc[:, ['A']].join(df.loc[:, 'K':'Y'])
```

If you want to select the columns 'numerically' you can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) instead of `loc`:

```
# Select first column and columns 11 through 25.
# We have to slice with 12:27 because indexing starts with 0,
# so 12 equals to column number 11. The destination index '27'
# equals to column 26, from which we have to subtract 1 because
# the last element is exclusive in numerical slicing.
df_new = df.iloc[:, [0]].join(df.iloc[:, 12:27])
```

Comment: Is there any alternative way where we do not have to depend on the column names or the alphabetical position/index of the column ? What if the sequence of the column names were jumbled like A,B,I,E,F,H,K...and so on and we have to obtain three dataframes such that the first dataframe consists of column 1 and columns 2 to 7, 2nd dataframe consists of column 1 and column 9 to 10 and third dataframe consists of column 1 and column 11 to column 25 ? I guess your method would work but I would be glad if I could somehow use the numeric positions/index of the columns.

Comment: I have extended my answer to demonstrate numerical slicing of columns. Please remember for future questions to make your intention clear right from the beginning, e. g. by asking 'Given column names A, B, D, Z, J, ... how can I extract columns 5 through 9?' That would make it easier for people to give you exactly the answer that you need to solve your specific problem

Comment: I shall certainly express my intentions in a better way. I apologize for the inconvenience. By the way, on using `iloc`, I am getting an error : `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join' `.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `df_new = df.iloc[:, [0]].join(...)`. Passing a list of numbers will return a DataFrame. Passing just a number will return a pandas Series and in consequence cause the AttributeError. I have corrected my answer accordingly. I would be very grateful if you could accept my answer if that ultimately solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am grateful.